# Error: resuming from hibernation

Tags: kali-linux, hibernate

I rebooted my laptop and it can't boot again. It stucked in "Resuming from hibernation":

```
invalid resume device: /dev/sda1
```

Please tell me what to do. I freed up space, still can't resolve this. 5.4.0-kali2-amd64

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/572522/edit) your post to include information on the Linux flavor and version you are using?

Comment: I edited it sir.

Comment: I really don't know what to do. Is there anything you can suggest?

Comment: Unfortunately, Kali is not a user-friendly linux distribution. Can you describe (again, edit) _how_ the system is hibernating (did you use a command-line tool, or was it via ACPI-trigger, e.g. closing the lid) and how you have configured it: hibernate with swap partition or swap file etc.

Comment: The last time I remembered doing before I rebooted it and turned like that is installed wine and wine32 and created a non-root account. After that, I rebooted my laptop and boom, it didn't open again.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to boot again edit the kernel command line in grub and add the option `noresume` as documented in [kernel's doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html).

Note that the state before hibernation will be lost (open document unsaved, etc...).

Comment: Uhhh how to add the noresume option?